# How to record sound on button clicked without MedaiRecorder Class...?

Tags: android, audio

I am developing an app in which I want to record the sound of each button which I pressed. But I dont want to record with Media Recorder class, as it record outer sounds also. but I don't want the outer sound to be recorded with those sounds.

Comment: it´s not possible to record internal sounds with the microfone.

Comment: instead You can make an array for example with the pressed sound resources, so it is possible to knwo which sounds where pressed

Comment: thanyou for the answer. Please check this app. Its doing the same thing... that I want.... https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paullipnyagov.drumpads24

Comment: Yes I know what You mean, but I think they really store the sound resource on button press, which could be for example in the raw folder. This could be something like ArrayList<Integer> soundList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); and then add the resource with soundList.add(R.raw.mySound) or something like this. But there are many different ways to do this, but not with recording internal sounds.

Comment: thankyou for your comment. Ca you help me in adding two sound file which are in raw folder, like sound1.mp3+sound2.mp3=sound.mp3